# DownloadManager : File size

Tags: java, android, url, size, android-download-manager

## DownloadManager : File size problem

Hello world! I have a file size problem when i download my file with `DownloadManager`. 
The problem is that at the beginning of the file, the path is included as additional bytes. Moreover, I have the same problem when I download the my file with `curl`. Finally I am really lost because i'm using the same methods of download on `IOS` but it works.

I have a simple code like that :

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(file_url));

request.setDescription("Download the File " + file_id); 
request.setTitle("File " + file_id); 

request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, file_id, file_id);

return getDownloadManager().enqueue(request); /* <- downloadID */

DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
q.setFilterById(downloadID);

final Cursor cursor = DownloadFileManager.getInstance(context).getDownloadManager().query(q);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
```

But when I print `DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES` the size are already smaller than the real file size bytes.

#### For example :

- Data length : `775328 bytes`
- Data length when i download it : `775638 bytes`

If you have any clue to help can you help me.

Comment: Please tell the file size of the downloaded file. And the file size on the server before download.

Comment: You can try to get the file at this url : “https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3QTG0y1VFdlbEc3cUpJSVpqclU”
The file size on Google drive is 62160 bytes but when I download it I get 62263 bytes.

Comment: That link does not work without the right account info/rights. I wonder how the download manager can handle such an url.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The url is : [https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1O6oGNLaQweYzRpZ0ItSmVyNTA](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1O6oGNLaQweYzRpZ0ItSmVyNTA)

Comment: The same. It needs a google account. Try that link on your pc and you will see. Well i think. A pc/device without google drive. Please put google drive in the subject of your post. And add such a tag.

Comment: Dose it work ? i edit the previous comment.

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: How can I easily send the file to you?

Comment: Why would you? You better provide a public link.

Comment: Can you try this link so ? : [https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B3QTG0y1VFdlbEc3cUpJSVpqclU](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B3QTG0y1VFdlbEc3cUpJSVpqclU)

Comment: I will not try it. You have not done what i asked you to do.

Comment: The file is locally so i can't give you access. Do you prefer a dropbox link ?